# want to get all minimum values, including duplicates values

Tags: sql, oracle

'''
select min(ps_supplycost) as "cheapest"
from partsupp
where ps_partkey = 3753;
'''

Comment: Now is a good time to read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: ``select * from partsupp where ps_supplycost in (select min(ps_supplycost) from partsupp where ps_partkey = 3753) and ps_partkey = 3753;``

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT ps_supplycost AS cheapest
FROM   partsupp
WHERE  ps_partkey = 3753
ORDER BY ps_supplycost ASC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```